# "DROP SCHEMA" ORACLE SQL statement is not documented on docs.oracle.com

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently trying to wrap my head around how the documentation of the Oracle's database including their implementation of SQL is structured.

There are pages documenting the CREATE SCHEMA and DROP statements for other type of objects. But extensive search of the documentation hasn't yielded any results concerning the "DROP SCHEMA" statement.

What principle one should abide to in their Oracle documentation search to find the subject of interest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can `create schema`, there's no `drop schema`. Schema represents Oracle user along with its objects (tables, views, procedures, ...). If you want to get rid of it, you'd just `DROP USER`.

---

Note (in [CREATE SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6016.htm#SQLRF01313)) documentation says:

> This statement does not actually create a schema. Oracle Database automatically creates a schema when you create a user (see CREATE USER). This statement lets you populate your schema with tables and views and grant privileges on those objects without having to issue multiple SQL statements in multiple transactions.

Therefore, if you want to remove certain **objects** from your schema (i.e. not everything it contains, i.e. user itself), you'd do it one-by-one. Not necessarily in such a tedious way, though - you can create a PL/SQL procedure which drops e.g. views you created, or procedures, or whatever else. Tables are kind of *tricky* because of foreign key constraints, though.

Comment: One thing that lead me into believing that there should exist `DROP SCHEMA` statement, is that I have stumbled upon the documentation of the exact statement for the ancient Java DB SQL while searching docs.oracle.com

Comment: Right; it is Google to blame :), it returns Java DB documentation on top which confuses people. Just recently we've had a similar question here - someone read documentation related to Java DB, not Oracle itself.

Comment: To simplify dropping when there's FKs, you can use `drop table ... cascade constraints`

Comment: Right, @Chris, thank you. I was thinking about dropping subset of tables which are linked to other tables via "chain" of foreign keys so if you wanted to drop "this" table and leave "that" one and keep FK "alive" ... but yes, I'm probably overcomplicating it. CASCADE CONSTRAINTS it is.